# How to hide UI elements from external applications?

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, mediarecorder

I'm developing an android app. I'm recording the screen using `MediaRecorder` and `MediaProjection`. But I need no **external** UI elements to be shown except the application UI elements when recording screen, like those like Messenger chat heads or others.

How can I achieve that to disable or hide external UI elements?

Comment: What is a purpose of your recording? To make a demo? Than you may use "Demo mode" from Developer options of your device

Comment: To record Augmented Reality.